# How can I switch textarea to multiline when overflown with text?

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to have any input (  element in this case I guess) like in Whatsapp or Telegram. It should be 1 line by default. But when a line is overflown with text it should become 2-line textarea. And when the second line is also overflown, it should become a 3-line textarea. And vice versa.
I have no idea how to implement this. My first thought was to count input text characters and then change the lines depending on the amount of symbols. But then I realized it was a bad idea because different characters have different width. And a string "wwwwwwwwww" is wider than "iiiiiiiiii" when the font is Arial, but both strings have 10 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of the textarea element based on the scrollHeight property.  Here is an example using jQuery.  It could be simplified if used for a single textarea input.

```
$("#divContainingAutoSizingTextareas").on("keyup", "textarea:focus", function (e) {
    var textarea = $(":focus");
    textarea.height(textarea.prop("scrollHeight") - 12);
})
```

Here is an example without jQuery.  The purpose of resetting height is to cause the textarea to shrink when content is removed.  The purpose of the + 2 is to adjust for any styling that may make inconsistent results -- you can easily determine if the sizing is adjusting consistently and adjust accordingly.

```
document.getElementById("autoexpand").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("autoexpand");
    textarea.style.height = "34px";
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + "px";
})
```

Comment: I don't use jQuery and with plain JavaScipt I wrote this:
`textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";`
But it works sort of weird. The height expands as expected. But once expanded it shrinks in a strange way. -2px per event.
Let's say the height of textarea was 34px by default. Then it becomes 55px when is overflown with text. But then I start deleteing characters. When the textarea is not overflown anymore it becomes 53px, then 51px and all the way down to 33px. Then 34px again.

Comment: So adjust for the difference as `textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + "px";`  If you want the textarea to shrink when content is removed, reset the size before expanding as `textarea.style.height = "34px";`